# Can't upload text value to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I submit the form of my website,It only create a new ID.But all other value is empty, what should I do?

[image: screenshot of table]

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1); 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "seamaszhou";
$password = "123456";
$dbname = "guest";




$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
$password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO guest 
(guestName,guestEmail,guestContent) 
VALUES (:guestName, :guestEmail, :guestContent)");

$stmt->bindParam(':guestName', $guestName);
$stmt->bindParam(':guestEmail', $guestEmail);
$stmt->bindParam(':guestContent', $guestContent);

// insert a row
$guestName = "$guestName";
$guestContent = "$guestContent";
$guestEmail = "$guestEmail";
$stmt->execute();



?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're not setting any values.  When you do this:

```
$guestName = "$guestName";
```

The variable `$guestName` gets set to a string containing the current value of the variable `$guestName`.  Since it doesn't contain anything, you're just setting it to an empty string.

Use actual values.  For example:

```
$guestName = "Some name";
```

Or, if you literally wanted that variable name as a string, use single-quotes so it doesn't get interpreted as a variable:

```
$guestName = '$guestName';
```

Comment: See the [PHP manual about Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and read about "variable expansion."

Comment: Thanks for help David. I actually want to make a form to let the user fill this information and then submit to my server. What should I do for that? I tried '$guestContent=$_POST['guestContent'];' but seems not work.

Comment: @seamaszhou: What doesn't work about it?  Is that value being posted in the first place?  The code shown doesn't include any HTML form, which you would need in order to, well, have an HTML form.

Comment: <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
  
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" 
    name="guestName" id="guestName" />
       
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" name="guestEmail" id="guestEmail" />
       
            <textarea name="guestContent" class="form-control" id="guestContent" rows="5"></textarea>
        
   
            <input type="submit" name="button" id="submit" value="Send to Us" class="btn"/>
         
    </form>

Comment: @David: Hey david. here are some part of my code about the form. Can you tell me how to makes it work with the php code above?

Comment: @seamaszhou: You seem to have forgotten to include the form's *action*.  Note where you have `action=""`.  This would cause the form to post to *the same page*.  If the code you're showing is the page you're loading to *display* the form then no form values are going to be present when you first display it.  So you'd be inserting an empty row any time you view the form.

Comment: @David Seems like the OP reposted https://stackoverflow.com/q/46744901/1415724 and I closed it.